# Don't show "Search for similar questions" and "Browse popular tags", etc., on 404 pages where they shouldn't be shown

Tags: feature-request, design, 404-not-found

If you browse to a 404 page such as https://meta.stackexchange.com/tools/screwdrivers or https://stackoverflow.com/ingenuity/free-unicorns, it shows the standard 404 page:

[image]

Except that in `/tools` and under, there are no questions or popular tags, so that info isn't really helpful.  Same with `/review`.  For pages where that information doesn't apply, could we show it like this:

[image]

Or replace that with some relative info and only show the standard image on 404 pages under `/questions`?

Comment: Wait, free waffles are not a thing? :'(

Comment: I feel that these links are actually helpful. Instead of just saying 'page not found' they are providing something for the user to do. The `recent questions` and `popular tags` links do not have to be connected with the link you are accessing. They are merely suggesting something to do.

Comment: @Mohammad Suggesting something for the user to do that is not in any way related to that page (e.g. `/tools`) isn't really great.  If you're going to put some links there at least make them relevant.